# Error sf: no simple features geometry column present

Tags: r, r-sf

I tried to import an ESRI shapefile with sf with the following code:

```
test = st_read("mont.shp", package="sf")
```

However, I get the error message:

```
Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : 
  no simple features geometry column present
```

Can somebody please help me? That would be great!

Cheers, Bas

Import ESRI shapefile with SF, error 'no simple features geometry column present'.

Comment: link to the shapefile?

Comment: What does `list.files(pattern = "mont" )` return?

Comment: Get rid of the `package = "sf"` argument. That's just for reading the sample data that comes with `sf`. I understand the confusion though, it is used in the help file examples.